# Replacing Hubspot API key with Privateapp access token in PHP

Tags: php, access-token, hubspot-api

I want to replace my Hubspot API key with private app access token in my application as per the doc https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/private-apps. I couldn't find any proper doc to start this with PHP. Currently below code is using to create URL.

```
/**
     * Creates the url to be used for the api request
     *
     * @param endpoint: String value for the endpoint to be used (appears after version in url)
     * @param params: Array containing query parameters and values
     *
     * @returns String
     */
    protected function get_request_url($endpoint, $params)
    {

        $paramstring = $this->array_to_params($params);

        return $this->get_domain() . $this->PATH_DIV.$this->get_api() . $this->PATH_DIV . $this->get_api_version() .
               $this->PATH_DIV . $endpoint . $this->KEY_PARAM . $this->HAPIKey . $paramstring;
    }
```

Please advice me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With Private Apps the connection is using OAuth2 only instead of the key being the access_token from the normal OAuth process, the key is the Private App key.

So if you are manually building/sending the URL you'll have to include headers to include `Authorization: Bearer <private-app-token>`.

If using a library like hubspot-php that translates to (if using their Factory method):

```
...
// Instead of token stored from normal OAuth2 exchange
// $config = ['key' => $token->access_token, 'oauth2' => true];

// The token is the Private App key, treat as OAuth2 token
$config = ['key' => '<private-app-token>', 'oauth2' => true];
$hubspot_client = new \SevenShores\Hubspot\Factory(
   $config,
   \SevenShores\Hubspot\Http\Client($config, $guzzleClient),
   [ 'http_errors' => false ],
   true
);
```

The idea is the same for the other OAuth2 connection examples in the hubspot-php and hubspot-api-php documentation. The Private App key simply replaces the token you'd normally receive in a OAuth2 initiation or refresh, but you don't have to build out support for those functions as the Private App key doesn't expire every couple hours.